# installing shopware 6 on windows with docker

Tags: docker, dockerfile, shopware

I am trying to install shopware 6 on a windows 10 machine with docker.
Docker seems to work, if I run: "docker --version" I get:

```
Docker version 18.09.2, build 6247962
```

and if I run: "docker run hello-world" I get:

```
This message shows that your installation appears to be working correctly.
```

But if I try to run: "psh.phar docker:start" as mentioned in the sw6 Installation guide (https://docs.shopware.com/en/shopware-platform-dev-en/getting-started/installation-guide#docker-installation-recommended) nothing happens.
There is no error or message, just nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

phar files will require a running php instance on your windows. Try "php -v" to check if your windows can use php. Otherwhise you need to installl it. Running docker native on windows might cause some additional issues, so you might want to run it inside the linux subsystem to avoid those issues.

Comment: "php -v" output "PHP 7.2.13 (cli)" so i guess its running. How can I run something inside the linux subsystem?